# Validating Pydantic field while setting value

Tags: python-3.x, validation, pydantic

A Pydantic class that has `confloat` field cannot be initialised if the value provided for it is outside specified range. But when setting this field at later stage (`my_object.constrained_field = <big_value>`) the new value is not validated.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, confloat

class testClass(BaseModel):
    a: confloat(gt=0.0, lt=10.0)

x = testClass(a=2.0) # OK

# x = testClass(a=20.0) # ERROR: outside limits

x.a = 40.0 # OK despite outside limits

print(x.a) # prints '40.0'
```

Is this possible to validate new value when setting member, so that calling `x.a = 40.0` in the example above will raise an exception?

If not -is there any workaround like getting validator method out of the class field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `validate_assignment` on [Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/).

Comment: Do you see any reason why `validate_assignment` is not `True` by default?

Comment: It has a performance impact and I would argue that the majority of cases wouldn't expect it to be on by default.

Comment: curious- does this cause root validators to be re-triggered?